# Remembering the Syntax for adding a list inside a list

Tags: c#, xamarin

there I have done this before but forgotten the syntax. I am making a JSON file which looks list the classes below but on the submit button I want to add them but I can't remember the syntax for when there is a list inside a list if that makes sense! my classes are:

```
public class LineItemCheck
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Check { get; set; }
        public bool Yes { get; set; }
        public bool No { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineItem
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<LineItemCheck> LineItemChecks { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public object SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public object UnitNumber { get; set; }
        public object Refrigerant { get; set; }
        public object ModelNumber { get; set; }
        public object BeltSize { get; set; }
        public object FreezingUnitComments { get; set; }
        public object VisualInspectionComments { get; set; }
        public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    }


    private void SubmitButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checklist = new RootObject();
        var checklistLineItem = new List<LineItem>();
        var checklistLineItemChecks = new List<LineItemCheck>();


        checklist.SerialNumber = SerialNumber.Text.ToString();
        checklist.UnitNumber = UnitNumber.Text.ToString();
        checklist.Refrigerant = Refrigerant.Text.ToString();
        checklist.ModelNumber = ModelNumber.Text.ToString();
        checklist.BeltSize = BeltSize.Text.ToString();

        checklistLineItem.Add(new LineItem() {
            Category = "Ziegra Machines Only",
            LineItemChecks = new LineItemCheck(LineItemCheck.
            ),



        });
```

as you can see the bottom section is wrong which is what i am trying to solve thanks

UPDATE: I remember the syntax myself sorry for posting but the answer i was looking for was:

```
var checklist = new RootObject();
        var checklistLineItem = new List<LineItem>();
        var checklistLineItemChecks = new List<LineItemCheck>();


        checklist.SerialNumber = SerialNumber.Text.ToString();
        checklist.UnitNumber = UnitNumber.Text.ToString();
        checklist.Refrigerant = Refrigerant.Text.ToString();
        checklist.ModelNumber = ModelNumber.Text.ToString();
        checklist.BeltSize = BeltSize.Text.ToString();

        checklistLineItem.Add(new LineItem() {
            Category = "Ziegra Machines Only",
            LineItemChecks = new List<LineItemCheck>()
            {
                new LineItemCheck()
                {
                    Check = "",
                },
                new LineItemCheck()
                {
                    Check = ""
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Daniel I have overwritten that for the but how is it added in the ChecklistLineIItem.Add section?

Comment: Are you trying to add an empty list to the new LineItem?

Comment: I think the question was not really clear. But glad you've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the following should be the right syntax:

```
        checklistLineItem.Add(new LineItem()
        {
            Category = "Ziegra Machines Only",
            LineItemChecks = new List<LineItemCheck>()
            {
                new LineItemCheck(),
                new LineItemCheck(), ...
            },
        });
```

Comment: Great this was it i just solved it myself as you posted this xD thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If I may: I would amend your models like so.

```
public class LineItem
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<LineItemCheck> LineItemChecks { get; private set; }

    public LineItem()
    {
         LineItemChecks = new List<LineItemCheck>();
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public object SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public object UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public object Refrigerant { get; set; }
    public object ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public object BeltSize { get; set; }
    public object FreezingUnitComments { get; set; }
    public object VisualInspectionComments { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; private set; }


    public RootObject()
    {
         LineItems = new List<LineItem>();
    }

}
```

That is, initializing all the collections in a constructor. Properties that expose collections and that can be `null` are ugly and, more importantly, unexpected. I **never** expect a collection to be `null` if it's exposed through a property, I expect it to **just be empty**, and that **I can add stuff to it** right away. I'm not in charge of a collection exposed by your object, it's your object's business to initialize itself properly.

This is the consensus in .NET land, you will be hard-pressed to find an example of a collection exposed by a library that is `null` upon instantiation of the object.

Also notice that I made the setters private, because no other object should be able to flat-out replace a collection exposed by a different object.

Then adding items to collections is simply a matter of:

```
var root = new RootObject();
var lineItem = new LineItem();
lineItem.LineItemChecks.Add(new LineItemCheck() { /* init properties here */ });
root.LineItems.Add(lineItem);
```